# How to limit the input on a 2D array so it won't blow up?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a small program, where i say the number of lines and columns of a array I want to input, then input info to fill that array with data. What it does next it's not important so ill just omit that part of the code and put (...) in it.

```
int main (){
int nl, nc,i,j,z,n;

scanf ("%d %d\n", &nl,&nc);

char matrix [nl] [nc];

for (i=0;i<nl;i++)
    for (j=0;j<nc;j++)
        scanf(" %c",&matrix[i][j]);
scanf("%d",&n);

int s[n*2];

for (z=0;z<n*2;z++)
scanf("%d",&s[z]);

int y=0;
char s2[n];
for (z=0;z<n*2;z+=2){
s2[y]=matrix [(s[z])-1][(s[z+1])-1];
y++;
}

for (z=0;z<n;z++)
printf ("%c", s2[z]);
return 0;
}
```

My problem is, that it this blows up if input more chars than I should. For example if my input is:

```
2 3
ABC
DEF
```

This works just fine.

But if I put:

```
2 3
ABC
DEFF
```

It give me a segmentation fold and stops the program. Keep in mind that I have a space before the "%c" in scanf so it's ignoring the "\n" and spaces I put in the input.

What can I do to stop that extra chars in the array from blowing up?

Comment: Not reproducible. [Live demo](http://ideone.com/76TDfx). Your error is elsewhere.

Comment: Hi @n.m., i can put the rest of the code if you want... The next step is another scanf. Why should i have a segmentation fold with another input?

Comment: It is hard to figure out why a program crashes without seeing a program that crashes. You decide whether you want to post one.

Comment: @n.m. here you have the full code: http://ideone.com/qy50P6

Comment: Please include the code in the question itself.

Comment: @n.m. i've added the code to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured out that the problem with it was input going to the buffer. To solve this i cleared the buffer before the next input using:

```
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d",&n);

int s[n*2];
```

This code tries to scan and convert whatever is left in the input after reading the matrix. If the input is not numeric, as will be the case if you enter more letters than the matrix should contain, the conversion will fail and `n` will remain uninitialized. Then `int s[n*2];` is undefined because `n` is indeterminate.

If you want to ignore some characters in the input, you need to do so explicitly. You also better check return values of all functions that take user input, and verify that the values read are sensible.

Comment: Oh i understand the problem... Can you help me with that restriction to ignore all the characters i input more? I thought i had that limited out with the for cicles.

Comment: Your nested `for` loops read exactly `nl*nc` non-whitespace characters. If you want something else, describe precisely what you want. You cannot read and ignore *all* the characters because you need to stop with the matrix at some point and start dealing with `n` and all the rest. You need to be able to describe precisely what that point is.

Comment: What i want is a way to just delete that extra chars that i input when reading the array, so there isn't any info on the buffer when reading n from input... That's all i want :)

Comment: Which ones are extra? Anyway this should be a separate question.

Comment: The ones that are outside my defined array... that go outside the for loops

Comment: All characters after `nl*nc` are outside of your array. You need to decide which ones you want to ignore and when you want to stop ignoring and start reading again.

Comment: I will not comment in this questions any more because the topic has drifted off the original question. Please ask a separate question if you have one.

Comment: Ok, i've figured a solution. I wanted to clear the input buffer that's all n.m.. Just added "while (getchar() != '\n');" before the scanf. That clears the buffer and works fine :D Thanks for the tip on figuring out what the problem was ;)

Comment: It hasn't shifted at all... The question is still the same... How to limit the input so it won't blow up...

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is filling the array over that size.

You get your input character by character and if you enter character more than your array size the program will stopped or has been logical error,

So you can  use getche() and check the array constraint.

You can edit your code as follow:

```
int main (){
int nl, nc,i,j;

scanf ("%d %d\n", &nl,&nc);

char matrix [nl] [nc];

for (i=0;i<nl;i++)
    for (j=0;j<nc;j++)
        matrix[i][j]=getche();
(...)
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gives me a error, probably i have to use some library. I've tried it with getchar() (only function we have learned so far that looks like that i guess) and it still gives segmentation fold... :/

Comment: This "analysis" is totally wrong and has nothing to do with the real reason of the crash (and `getche()` is non-standard and deprecated and does not in general do what's needed).

Answer (score -2):

Use `%s` instead of `%c` and remove the inner loop. So the code will be something like this:

```
for(i=0; i<nl; i++)
{
  scanf("%s", &matrix[i]);
}
```

Comment: This "answer" is totally wrong because of the buffer overflow and because of the terminating NUL character.

Comment: yeah i am sorry . my bad